# MacVim in Yosemite can't fullscreen

Tags: vim, osx-yosemite

I'm using Mac Yosemite 10.10.2 and newest macvim, but when I use fullscreen mode, the lines at the top of screen will be black, and if I move my mouse there, it will show the system line.[image: this is my problem]. 
I want to get my fullscreen back.

Comment: maybe need to submit an issue on the project instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue, happened me. A couple of work a rounds are:

1. Uncheck "Prefer native full-screen support" in preferences.
2. Open a second tab. This repositions the text and view correctly.

There is also a .diff patch on https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=514#c2

Answer (score 7):

A answer from [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/156631)

I found this post that seems to address that problem.

[Full screen MacVim on OS X Yosemite](http://shorts.jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/full-screen-macvim-on-yosemite/)

```
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMNativeFullScreen 0
```

It works for my MacVim.

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: @d13 input "defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMNativeFullScreen 0"  into terminal

Comment: Is this identical to option 1 in @Bytecus' answer?

Comment: This works, but how does one get out of the fullscreen?

Comment: @yatisagade u can use shortcut ctrl+command+F toggle full screen mode Or move mouse up to top of window

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're opening MacVim from the command line, use `open -a MacVim` instead of `mvim`. Fullscreen wasn't working for me either (I open from the command line a lot), but a friend shared this little tip and now fullscreen is again functional. Using `open -a MacVim` allows you to use native fullscreen, as well.

I'm running MacVim on Yosemite version 10.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot 77, the [latest macvim-dev/macvim release](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/latest) fixes the full screen mode rendering glitch in OS X Yosemite. You can download a pre-compiled executable installer from the release page (thanks to @jcl for [giving the links to the new repository and release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212989/1399315)). Or you can [install via brew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789830/1399315) as described by @greggannicott.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line into ~/.gvimrc (create that file if none exists):

```
set fu
```

MacVim will now always start in fullscreen mode!

Comment: This was amazing!! Thank you so much!